# Specific named range does not exist in .Names

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through both the workbook and worksheet .Names collection of a workbook that I have opened remotely. For some reason, some of the named ranges in that workbook are not included in the .Names collection. If I open the workbook and go to the name manager, I can see them in there. But they don't come through when I loop through the collection:

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
Dim book As Excel.Workbook, wbReport As Excel.Workbook
Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
app.visible = False

For Each nr In book.Names
    Debug.Print nr.Name
Next nr
For Each ws In book.Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    For Each wsnr In ws.Names
        Debug.Print wsnr.Name
    Next
Next ws
```

Please note that the file path is definitely correct and I do see *some* of the named ranges but not others.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please check `Debug.Print nr.Parent.Name`. Just to confirm you are in the correct workbook. Even `nr.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` to check on which sheet.

Comment: What are the definitions of some of the Named Ranges that are *not* showing up? Can you discern a pattern from what they refer to?

Comment: I @JvdV I did do debug.print nr.referstorange.parent.name and it is correct. I even added more named ranges to the workbook and tested again and they come up correctly

Comment: Cindy Meister - one of them actually refers to a second named range. The other is a simple value.

Comment: If you have declared a Range as a Table-Object. Then you will need to loop through the `Worksheet.ListObjects` as well to get their names.

Comment: Have you used `Debug.Print` on `.Names.Count` to check how many it can "see"?

Comment: @M.Getrost Thank you! Using `Worksheet.ListObjects` was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Worksheet.Names` will only return a collection of the named ranges. If there are additionally named tables in the worksheet, then one has to loop through the `Worksheet.ListObject`'s as well.